# Adding scrolling to custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom view that have lots of data in it to be shown and I am wondering should I use a `Scrollview` to scroll it? If I used a `ScrollView` does this means that all the data of my view will be drawn in the `OnDraw()` even though they cannot be shown? Or should I implement my scrolling and draw only data that can be shown and on scroll draw other data according to scroll offset?

One more thing the

```
computeVerticalScrollExtent() 
//Compute the vertical extent of the horizontal scrollbar's thumb within the 
//vertical range.
```

I don't get this shouldn't it be of the vertical scroll bar's thumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your view in a ScrollView with hardware acceleration enabled (on by default if your Target API level is >= 14) then `onDraw()` will be called only once for your whole view and everything your app draws is cached in so-called [display lists](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#model).

This works fine unless your view gets really large (e.g. a text editor with thousands of lines).

Comment: but my target is >= 8 so I should use custom scrolling then?

Comment: Without hardware acceleration only the visible parts of your View will be drawn (no caching) which is usually quite fast too. So unless you target API level >= 14 _and_ have a hug view within the ScrollView you should be fine.

Comment: hmmmm, I still dont get it. My view has an `onDraw()` method that when is called it should draw the whole scene as it dont check to see boundaries or anything then If I put it on scrollview only the visible part will be drawn? though the `onDraw()` method have drawn everything? ye I know it won't be visible on screen but the drawing calculation and every thing for the whole scene has been made in the `onDraw()` right?

Comment: No, you should only draw the parts affecting the rectangle returned by [Canvas.getClipBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getClipBounds())